# Setting variable states before testing in Truffle

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

Can you set variables inside a smart contract before running your tests. I'm thinking of testing functions that won't pass when a variable has reached a certain number.

I.E.

```
1. Write a function that will only run when var_1 >= 800
2. Write a test where var_1 is = 799 and the test confirms the function fails
3. Write a test where var_1 is = 801 and the test confirms the function succeeds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, something like this?

```js
const { exptect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("contract test" () => {
  let contract;
  
   beforeEach(async () => {
    // Before each test, we create a new contract instance, this is to prevent contract modifications between tests, and having each test executed without the interference of contract modification other tests.
    let Contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("Contract");
    await contract = Contract.deploy();
    await contract.deployed();
   });
   
   // Write a test where var_1 is = 799 and the test confirms the function fails.
   it("Should fail if var_1 is = 799", async () => {
   
      // set var_1 value.
      const tx = await contract.setVar1(799);
      await tx.wait();
      
      // Test function excepts...
      ...
   });
}
```

Comment: Does that work if var_1 is declared in the main contract as `uint256 var_1 = 1;`? (i.e. var_1 is not public)

Comment: I didn't quite grasp the question, If you have a setter or if the variable is public, yeah, either way, you can't change the value of a state variable, and about the type, `ethers` usually handle the forwarded value to the contract, you just have to make sure the value you're setting is compatible with the type of unit you're using or you'll get an overflow, also take special care of Big Numbers.

Comment: Cool. I've got you. Thanks